# filter an array based on multiple arrays using some()

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

It's quite possible I am going about this the wrong way, but I have a primary array that i need to filter if any of it's objects values exist in two other arrays. I am trying to use a combination of `filter()` and `some()` but what I have right now is not working.

```
const milestones = <FormArray>this.piForm.get('_milestones');
if (this.piById) {
    milestonesToCreate = milestones.value
        .filter(milestone => !this.piById.milestones.some(item => item.milestoneId === milestone.milestoneId));
    milestonesToDelete = this.piById.milestones
        .filter(milestone => !milestones.value.some(item => item.milestoneId === milestone.milestoneId));
    milestonesToUpdate = milestones.value
        .filter(milestone => milestones.value
            .some(item =>
                item.milestoneId === milestonesToCreate.milestoneId && milestonesToDelete.milestoneId));
}
```

In the code above `milestonesToUpdate` should be a the filtered results where the array consists of objects that are not in `milestonesToCreate` and `milestonesToDelete`

Hopefully I've explained this well enough.

ADDED SAMPLE MILESTONES ARRAY

```
milestones = [
  {
    "milestoneId": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: issue in your code is your are checking `=== milestonesToCreate.milestoneId` but `milestonesToCreate` is a list so does not contain such a property. for you approach you need to iterate through `milestonesToCreate` and check `.milestoneId` for each element there

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of `milestones` / your `expected output`?

Comment: @ArmanCharan I put a sample in my OP

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it looks like your problem is just a misunderstanding of boolean checks in your final call to `some()`.

You have put:

```
item.milestoneId === milestonesToCreate.milestoneId && milestonesToDelete.milestoneId
```

Which is the same as saying, *where item.milestoneId equals milestonesToCreate.milestoneId AND milestonesToDelete.milestoneId exists*. I expect that you are just trying to check if the current value exists in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to achieve that in single pass:

1. put all elements to `elementsToUpdate`, copy all elements from your `this` into `elementsToDelete`
2. iterate through `elementsToUpdate`, once some item does not exist in another list, move that element into `elementsToCreate`
3. if element exists in both, remove it from `elementsToDelete`.

   4. finally you will get 3 lists you need.

And you can even speed up code more if instead of using arrays you use hash(old good `{}`) where id are used as keys. Then check "if element is here" would be as easy as `item in elementsToUpdate` instead of iterating all the elements each time